# How to read Rediffmail and hotmail using IMAP

Tags: php, imap, email-client, email-parsing

I am trying to access all unread emails of rediff and hotmail using PHP IMAP. I am trying to use imap.live.com:995/imap/ssl as host name for rediffmail but it failed with an error no host found. But when i try for gmail it works. 
     gmail : IMAP HOSTNAME '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX' POP3 HOSTNAME: '{pop.gmail.com:993/ipop3/ssl}INBOX' Does Rediffmail and Hotmail provide any such service to access mailbox.

Comment: First, are you using POP3 or IMAP?  995 is a POP3 port.  In Summary: IMAP: 143.  IMAP/SSL: 993.  POP3: 110.  POP3/SSL:995.  Have you used any external tools, like telnet, socat, or openssl s_client to probe the settings yourself?

Comment: Indeed, have you even done a web search.  http://www.limilabs.com/blog/hotmail-imap-pop3-smtp-settings indicates some IMAP settings that appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

Hotmail IMAP server settings

Server address: imap-mail.outlook.com

port: 993

So your url will be  imap-mail.outlook.com:993/imap/ssl

Answer (score 0):

imap.rediffmail.com port 143. 143 is the default port for IMAP. May I ask why you didn't try that yourself?

Comment: Error opening mailbox: TLS/SSL failure for imap.rediffmail.com: Invalid token, probably not an SSL server

Comment: I think redifmail only support pop with pop.rediffmail.com. It only supports rediffmailpro with imap mail server for that imap.rediffmailpro.com, which doesn't work for normal rediff email.

Comment: Ah, well, I suppose they've turned it off. It did work when I tested it in January 2014.